# Spyder: run a command in debug mode

Tags: python, spyder

I want to use the Spyder debugger (`ipdb` or whatever it is) from the console. It seems like the only way to enter the debugger is with the "Debug file" command, which requires me to make a dedicated file every time I want to debug something. It seems like there must be a way to do this that I just haven't found.

Comment: why not use `pycharm` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it (although it has what I consider to be a bug).

```
%debug result = my_cool_function(stuff)
```

The bug is that the debugger stops immediately, as if there were a breakpoint. I then have to press `Ctrl-F12` to advance.